# Set list as index of Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I have the following list:

```
index_list =  ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h']
```

I would like to use it to define an index for the following DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(index= [0,1,4,7])
```

The DataFrames index corresponds to an entry in the list. The end result should look like:

```
df_target = pd.DataFrame(index= ['a','b','e','h'])
```

I have tried a number of built in functions for pandas, but no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Index.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.map.html) with dictonary created by `enumerate`:

```
target_df = pd.DataFrame(index=df.index.map(dict(enumerate(index_list))))
print (target_df)
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: [a, b, e, h]
```

If need change index in existing DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':range(4)}, index= [0,1,4,7])
print (df)
   a
0  0
1  1
4  2
7  3

df = df.rename(dict(enumerate(index_list)))
print (df)
   a
a  0
b  1
e  2
h  3
```

Answer (score 0):

like this:

```
print(pd.DataFrame(index=[index_list[i] for i in [0,1,4,7]]))
```

Output:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: [a, b, e, h]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a Series object to [Index.map](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.map.html) method.

```py
df.index.map(pd.Series(index_list))


# Index(['a', 'b', 'e', 'h'], dtype='object')
```

Or rename the Dataframe index directly

```py
df.rename(index=pd.Series(index_list))

# Empty DataFrame
# Columns: []
# Index: [a, b, e, h]
```